# Tibco Administrator

Tags: tibco, tibco-topic

Where does the Tibco Administrator GUI get the status of applications and services?

In my project, I have a requirement to read the status of all the services listed in Tibco admin. I don't have Tibco hawk installed and I need some other alternative other than tibco hawk.

Answer (score 4):

What you can do is to store all the components status in a file with the following command :

```
AppStatusCheck -user ${ADMIN_USERNAME} -pw ${ADMIN_PASSWORD} -domain ${ADMIN_DOMAIN} -outfile /tmp/status.xml
```

And after that, you can use sed command or xmllint linux command to extract the status of all components.

Answer (score 3):

You can query the status of the applications via appmanage

Answer (score 1):

You can used the tra utility 'AppStatusCheck' which will return the status of that  particular application deployed over domain. You can used this utility in shell script to used it much better and efficient way.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a machine added to a domain, then that machine automatically installs tibco TRA Hawkagent, which sends information to Admnistrator about the status of the application.

Answer (score 0):

As you don't want to use HAWK, the other way on UNIX box will be PID of the services. HAWK will be using the same in the background. However it is bit tricky though.

Answer (score 0):

Each machine/host in TIBCO Administrator domain will be running a HawkAgent, and it is responsible gathering application status such as "Stopped", "Running".

If you have a requirement to script and gather application status, you can use the AppStatusCheck (comes with TRA 5.8 onwards) to fetch the applications and their status in an XML format.